# Solution Verification - convergence and divergence of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

*Please note that this is a solution verification question and am just checking the answer.*

An arbitrary series, $\sum a_n$, will converge to 3 given the following condition: $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| \to 3$. Which of the series will converge?

- $\sum n a_n$
- $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^2}$
- $\sum \frac{a_n}{2^n}$
- $\sum \frac{a_n}{4^n}$

Since I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| \to 3$, then I should perform the ratio test on the sum, $(n+1)a_{n+1} \div \frac{1}{n a_n}$ which gives $\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, which is $3 \frac{n+1}{n}$, evaluating the limit, this gives 3. So it diverges.

Using the same method as described, the second also results in 3, the third is $\frac{3}{2}$, and the fourth is $\frac{3}{4}$. According to the ratio test, only the fourth one will converge. Can someone verify this?

Comment: The question formulation is probably mis-copied, but your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An arbitrary series, $\sum a_n$, will converge to $3$ given the following condition: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = 3$. Which of the series will converge?

You are saying that the sum $\sum a_n$ converges. But then you are also saying that $L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| = 3$, which by the ratio test means that the sum is divergent (since $L>1$).

So you cannot answer the other four questions. Please edit your answer if you did a mistake.

Comment: Ok, I found it myself. It's fine :)